# Where to install a Python package - system wide or in a virtual env?

Tags: python-3.x, package, virtualenv

I have Python 3.7 installed (system-wide) along with packages like Numpy, Pandas, pptx, xlsxwriter, and some more. Recently, I learned about virtual environments (yes I am very late to the party), and clearly see the benefits. But I am confused about a few things. Hopefully I can get answers here.

1. In most of my projects, I use common packages like Numpy, Pandas, Matplotlib, mysql.connector, etc. Should I install these system-wide? Or should I install them in each virtual environment that I create for each project, which, for example, amounts to installing Pandas 10 times in 10 different virtual environments?
2. If I install packages (system wide) that are not part of the Python Standard Library, for example, pptx and mysql.connector, AND I create a virtual environment, will I have access to these packages from within a virtual environment, or should I install them in the virtual environment as well?
3. What about a module like jupyter notebook, where it is not part of any project specifically, but I love using it for simple code development and testing (simple plots, etc.). Should this be installed system wide?

I am considering un-installing Python 3.7 and all the packages from my computer, and doing a fresh install of Python 3.8. I want to approach this the "right" way. I would think packages like Numpy and Pandas (I do quite a bit of data manipulation/plotting) should be installed system wide, and each virtual environment should have access to it automatically, and a more specialized package (for me at least) like pptx should be installed in a particular virtual environment for a particular project. Is my assumption correct about this?

Please advise on how to best approach package installation in the context of having virtual environments.

EDIT: based on Ni's reply, I would ask one more question: Are there modules (for example, python-dateutil, that might be used in many projects) and/or circumstances where it makes sense to install a module system-wide?

Answer (score 3):

In general, I never install packages system wide.

1. You might install packages which require specific versions of Numpy, in your environments. In those cases, if you update the system wide version of Numpy, the package in the environment might break and you won't know that happened.
2. Yes, you can access them from virtual environment. But in general, don't install packages system wide
3. Again, I wouldn't install that system wide. For e.g., you might have environments running different python versions, which might not be compatible with the same version of Jupyter

Seems like you're doing a lot of data science work - you might want to use Anaconda to help you manage your virtual environments and package installations

Comment: Thanks Ni. I had installed Anaconda, but for some reason it conflicted with my attempt to make one of my tkinter projects executable. Also, over a 3 year period, I found myself not using more than a dozen modules at most. So I got rid of Anaconda, did a basic Python 3.7 install and installed 8-10 modules system wide. But I learned about venvs, and so decided to give it a try.